GDAL ogr2ogr ESRIJSON to PG Date Formatting
I'm trying to load some data from an Esri Feature Server URL into PostGIS, using ogr2ogr but seem to be facing some issues with the date formats.
The below code should in theory load all the World Heritage Sites within the UK into PostgreSQL.
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"[redacted connection string]" ESRIJSON:"https://services6.arcgis.com/eMd5K6XXEvJETxfQ/arcgis/rest/services/prd_whc_sites_dossiers_elements_view/FeatureServer/1/query?where=element_state+%3D+%27United+Kingdom+of+Great+Britain+and+Northern+Ireland%27&outFields=*&f=pjson" -nlt MULTIPOLYGON --config OGR_TRUNCATE YES -nln world_heritage_sites

The full error can be found at https://pastecode.io/s/k71y5sbv but the tl;dr is
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "1984/05/"

It would seem it's just not managed to parse the day into the date string it's trying to load into PostgreSQL. The Feature Server offers a Unix timestamp, which having checked manually looks fine. I'm not sure if it's a bug with one or other of the GDAL drivers / the ogr2ogr tool. I've tried it in two instances of postgres, each with different datestyle options - ISO, DMY and ISO, MDY - so I don't think that's the issue. I rather think it's just that however it does it's internal processing, it's managed to ditch the day from the date.
I seem to have gotten it working by going via GeoJSON, however this seems an unnecessary step and another point of potential failure in the future. I want to have this working for various layers, to run automatically at varying frequencies, so trying to do manual field mapping or anything is going to be very cumbersome.

There was some bug in setting the field width of the timestamp column. As a workaround use ogr2ogr with option -unsetFieldWidth https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-unsetFieldWidth

-unsetFieldWidth
Set field width and precision to 0.

I made a successful test with this command.
ogr2ogr PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=my_db user=user password=pw" esrijson.json -nln esrijson -overwrite -unsetfieldwidth -nlt multipolygon --debug on |moreogr2ogr PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=my_db user=user password=pw" ESRIJSON:"https://services6.arcgis.com/eMd5K6XXEvJETxfQ/arcgis/rest/services/prd_whc_sites_dossiers_elements_view/FeatureServer/1/query?where=element_state+%3D+%27United+Kingdom+of+Great+Britain+and+Northern+Ireland%27&outFields=*&f=pjson" -nlt multipolygon -nln esrijson -overwrite -unsetFieldWidth --debug on

Take care to use -overwrite instead of -truncate if the table exists, otherwise the field width will not be changed.
GDAL is already patched https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/commit/d9e48f9e862bc60ed6c1392a5e3528ffa3445c3d but it may take some time before the fix is available in a released version.
